# How can I print only consonants?

Tags: c++, dynamic

I have been asked to write a code to print only consonants using a dynamic array. I wrote a code to do that but it prints exactly the input without canceling out the vowels.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int len,i;
    cin>>len;
    char* pArray=new char[len];
    char ch[len];
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        cin>>ch[i];
    for(i =0;i<len;i++){
        if(ch[i]=='a' && ch[i]=='e' && ch[i]=='i' && ch[i]=='o' && ch[i]=='u')
            break;
        else
            pArray[i]=ch[i];
    }
    for( i=0;i<len;i++)
        cout<<(pArray[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

If I write the input `ample`, it should print only `mpl`.

Comment: Think about what this does, `pArray[i]=ch[i];` it copies the character at index `i` from `ch` to `pArray` also placing it at index `i`. But `pArray` is supposed to be shorter than `ch` after the vowels have been removed. So this cannot be right.

Comment: @bruno _"when `..` is false"_ i.e. always!

Comment: The issue here is that you need to think **clearly and precisely** about the steps needed to perform this task. It's no good just writing some loops and if statements that are roughly right and hoping that it will work.

Comment: I am a beginner and I am trying to figure this out. I seem to have hit the dead-end.

Comment: @FahimHassan Well think about this, in your program you have only one length variable, called `len`. But you have two strings `ch` and `pArray` that are different lengths. So how can that be right?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings ah yes I read wrong correcting OP code at the same time ^^

Comment: @FahimHassan do you understand your problems and how to solve them thanks to (at least) my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62049092/2458991) ?

Answer (score 1):

doing

```
for(i =0;i<len;i++){
    if(ch[i]=='a' && ch[i]=='e' && ch[i]=='i' && ch[i]=='o' && ch[i]=='u')
        break;
    else
        pArray[i]=ch[i];
}
```

the test `ch[i]=='a' && ch[i]=='e' && ch[i]=='i' && ch[i]=='o' && ch[i]=='u'` is always false because a character cannot be several at the same time.

you also need a dedicated index to write in *pArray* and not print after based on *len* but that additional index.

Also check `cin>>len;` success (and other use of `>>`) else you do with *len* is 0 and none of the next read success because you do not clear the error flag nor bypass the invalid input.

Note also there are not only vowel and consonant, so when a character is not vowel that does not means it is a consonant, what must be done for other characters ?

Do not use variable length arrays as you did for *ch*.

Out of that, why are you using array of characters rather than `std::string`, is it required by statement ?

---

based on your code minimal changes also managing uppercase character can be :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int len;

    if (!(cin>>len))
      cerr << "len is not a number" << endl;
    else if (len <= 0)
      cerr << "len must be > 0" << endl;
    else {
      char* pArray = new char[len];
      char* ch = new char[len];
      int i;

      for (i=0;i<len;i++){
        if (!(cin>>ch[i])) {
          cerr << "EOF, abort" << endl;
          return -1;
        }
        if (!isalpha(ch[i])) {
          cerr << "invalid character, abort" << endl;
          return -1;
        }
      }

      int j = 0;

      for(i =0;i<len;i++) {
        switch (ch[i]) {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
        case 'e':
        case 'E':
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
        case 'y': // is vowel no ?
        case 'Y': // is vowel no ?
          break;
        default:
          // suppose only consonant and vowel
          pArray[j++]=ch[i];
        }
      }

      for( i=0;i<j;i++)
        cout<<(pArray[i]);
      cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
5
ample
mpl
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: _"you stop at the first vowel"_ No, it iterates the entire string, because the condition cannot possibly be satisfied.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings you are right, I edited my answer

Comment: Looks like there are holes in the `pArray`.  I don't see how the same index can be used for `pArray` and `ch`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes, this is why I said an additional index is required if doing based on OP proposal

Answer (score 1):

Your program isn't working because of logic error. You have used && operator between each logical expression. So, whenever the compiler come across a character it checks whether the character is 'a' and 'e' and 'i' and 'o' and 'u', which is obviously not possible simultaneously at the same time. Use "||" operator instead of "&&". Also for entering character in pArray you need to define another integer for its index .

```
    int k=0;
    for(i =0;i<len;i++){
        if(ch[i]=='a' || ch[i]=='e' || ch[i]=='i' || ch[i]=='o' || ch[i]=='u')
            break;
        else
            {pArray[k]=ch[i]; k++;}
```

Comment: It should not break after a vowel is found. Otherwise, the program will copy until the first vowel truncating the input string.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few mistakes in your code. I'm feeling generous, see how you get on with this

```
int main()
{
    // read the word
    int length;
    cin >> length;
    char* word = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        cin >> word[i];
    // allocate enough space for the word without vowels
    char* no_vowels = new char[length];
    // copy the non-vowels
    int no_vowels_length = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if (word[i] != 'a' && word[i] != 'e' && word[i] != 'i' && word[i] != 'o' && word[i] != 'u')
        {
            // found a non-vowel, copy it to the end of the no-vowel word
            no_vowels[no_vowels_length] = word[i];
            // and increase the length of the no vowel word
            ++no_vowels_length;
        }
    }
    // write out the word without vowels
    for (int i = 0; i < no_vowels_length; ++i)
        cout << no_vowels[i];
}
```

I think the idea you are missing is that you need two variables for the lengths of your two different strings

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Quickly fixing the code inline:

every warning(1) error(4) is commented inline.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int len, i;
  cin >> len;
  char* pArray = new char[len];
  char* ch = new char[len];
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    cin >> ch[i];

  //WARNING: please note that pArray NOR ch isn't NULL terminated

  int j = 0; //ERROR 1: you need to count the inserted char
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    //ERROR 2: you need an OR in order to check for vowels, not an AND
    if (ch[i] == 'a' || ch[i] == 'e' || ch[i] == 'i' || ch[i] == 'o' || ch[i] == 'u')
      //ERROR 3: if found, do not break, instead skip the vowels...
      continue;
    else
      pArray[j++] = ch[i]; //ERROR 1bis: so you increment the j every time you insert a char
  }
  for (i = 0; i < j; i++) //ERROR 4: print out only the added lettere, indeed pArray is longer than needed (space for further improvement?)
    cout << (pArray[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps,
Stefano

Answer (score -1):

I believe there is a hole in your logic.  IMHO, you can't have the same index for the `ch` (source) array and the `pArray` (target or destination) array.

Draw out the source and target arrays:
Source (example):

```
+---+---+---+---+---+  
| H | e | l | l | o |  
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Target:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+  
|   |   |   |   |   |  
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

After ignoring the `e`, your Source will be pointing at the first 'l' and your target will be pointing at the 3rd slot in `pArray`:
Source (example):

```
+---+---+---+---+---+  
| H | e | l | l | o |  
+---+---+---+---+---+  
  0   1   2   3   4
```

Target:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+  
| H |   | l |   |   |  
+---+---+---+---+---+  
  0   1   2   3   4
```

In the simple version you will need to have one index that represents the "next" available slot in the target array, and one index that represents the current letter in the source array.

*(Or you could use another pointer to the target array and increment that)*

```
char * p_target_slot = pArray;
int target_index = 0;
for(i =0;i<len;i++)
{
    if(   ch[i]=='a'
       || ch[i]=='e'
       || ch[i]=='i'
       || ch[i]=='o'
       || ch[i]=='u')
        continue;
    else
    {
        *p_target_slot++ = ch[i];
        // Or you can use this:
        pArray[target_index] = ch[i];
        ++target_index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoters:  Please leave explanation, so I can improve my answer